Kotlinx LocalDate custom formatting
I am investigating the kotlinx DateTimeFormat and have multiple format use cases in my application which are all using the standard LocalDate.Format{} as shown below:
val formatter: DateTimeFormat<LocalDate> = LocalDate.Format {
                dayOfMonth();
                char(CHARACTER_SPACE);
                monthName(MonthNames.ENGLISH_ABBREVIATED);
                char(CHARACTER_SPACE);
                year();
}

however of the usecase formats is not covered e.g. full date with dayOfMonth() ordinal, such as "2nd Oct 2024" etc...
Is it possible to create a custom DateTimeFormat that can interrogate the dayOfMonth() value and add the required ordinal?

I don't think so… The README.md of https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime states The library is based on the ISO 8601 international standard, other ways to represent dates and times are out of its scope. Internationalization (such as locale-specific month and day names) is out the scope, too., and parsing locale-specific abbreviations is likely covered by that sentence.
